# What's the reason Yuuki employs only male spies?

Tags: joker-game

Haven't read the manga, but in the anime all the spies in D Agency are male.
Wouldn't it be beneficial for certain missions to have a female spy?

Answer (score 5):

Joker Game is set from 1937 and later. During this time, Japan was in its Imperial Era, where every male was required to serve in the [Imperial Army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_Japanese_Army). Many women were forced into gender roles that would not allow them to become soldiers in the war. You can read more about Japanese women's role in WWII [here](http://ethw.org/Japanese_Women_and_the_Japanese_War_Effort).

However, D-Agency is definitely under different leadership than the rest of the Imperial Army, as evidenced by most of the show. I think that despite their variance from then traditional ways in military leadership, *Yuuki still was not at the point where he could employ a woman as a spy due to the conservative and rigid gender roles at the time*. I do agree that for certain missions, a female spy would have been beneficial to D-Agency's goals, but I think the concept was too 'ahead of its time' for the late 1930s/early 1940s in Japan.